# wildfly migration from AS 7 to WF10

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-8, wildfly-9, wildfly-10

I am new to WildFly Server. I am upgrading server from AS7 to Wildfly10. How to add JARS in WILDFLY10. In Error Log: i am getting missing Dependencies(Is this because of not reading JARS?).

Comment: Please provide more information.  Can you show us what exactly is in the error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually we need to delete the servlet-mappings in web.xml and use annotations to direct to java classes
1. @webservlet for Servlet classes.
2. @path for resources.

Also we need to delete some unneccessary jars, which wildfly have inbuilt.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add jars like it is given on their wiki.

1. Sometimes you need to add a module (if it is a jar that is not
   shipped with Wildfly and define it in
   jboss-deployment-structure.xml).
2. Sometimes, in case it is already shipped (you may have to search inside the modules directory) and add it in jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Again it depends what is it saying. which dependency etc?
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly